# Definition of equivalence of optimization problems

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

Given some (convex, I guess) optimization problem, I am told that if it is of the form (max$\{f : \text{insert constraints here}\}$), then we can replace it with an 'equivalent' minimization problem, which is (min$\{-f : \text{same constraints as before}\}$). I understand that if $x$ optimizes the max problem, then it also optimizes the min problem, and vice-versa. However, my question is about the term 'equivalent'. It seems like in general, the objective functions of the max and min problems will not be equal, and hence the feasible solution outputs will not be equal.

My initial assumption was that 'equivalent' problems meant that they were in fact identical, up to formatting (meaning the max f vs. min -f), but this is clearly not the case. I still see how the problems are completely determined by each other, but this was still not what I had interpreted equivalent problems to be.

So, what is the definition of 'equivalent' convex optimization problems, and is there another term that we use when two problems are completely identical up to formatting, or is this not actually something we need to bother considering/defining?

Comment: @Renard how is that relevant to the OP? The dual and the original problems are not completely identical up to formatting; they work on very different spaces, and they are only equal in the settings where strong duality (KKT conditions or I guess Slater's) hold. (Though yes there is a tag of linear-programming, which was probably what is misleading)

As for OP, I have not heard of a specific term for what you are looking for, but you can probably repurpose the word "equivalent" to your setting. (And you can generate such problems by adding redundant constraints for instance)

Comment: @E-A thanks for the response. Good to know that at least I'm not missing a standard term/concept.